# Rails3 Kaminari pagination BUG?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I am using kaminari version - (0.12.4)

But when I am trying to use this for following

```
merchants = merchants.page(params[:page]).use_distinct(:id).per(2)
```

Its get an error

> undefined local variable or method `use_distinct' for
>   []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `#use_distinct` is not part of neither ActiveRecord nor Kaminari API. Where did you get that one?

To achieve something similar:

```
Model.select('DISTINCT id').page(params[:page]).per(2)
```